# Create base Django model class for DB-view related models setting all ForeignKey-fields to on_delete=DO_NOTHING

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django (1.6+) application, I have many Django models that point to (read only) DB views.
These models also contain foreign key relations.
Now if the Django application tries to delete the related fk-models, this will lead to DB errors ("Cannot delete from view") if I don't set  cascade=DO_NOTHING on *all* foreign key fields.

Example:

```
class PersonView(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='fk_person', on_delete=DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'view_persons'
        managed = False
```

Since all my db-view-model-ForeignKey-fields should have cascade=DO_NOTHING by default, I'd like to create a DB-View model base class which will automatically set all foreign-key-fields to on_delete=DO_NOTHING, so I only need to care for inheriting from this model - otherwise it's easy to forget (and redundant) setting this attribute for all fields. 
In the end I want to end up with a code like this:

```
class ViewModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ViewModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # How to set all foreign-key fields' on_delete attribute to "DO_NOTHING"? 

class PersonView(ViewModel):
    # no need to set on_delete anymore
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='fk_person')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'view_persons'
        managed = False
```

How can I alter Django model attributes in my base class to set all foreign key fields to on_delete=DO_NOTHING?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can monkey-patch `models.ForeignKey` but the more preferred method is to simply subclass `ForeignKey`:

```
class MyForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForeignKey, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING
```

Then you can use `MyForeignKey` instead of `ForeignKey` in your models.

Comment: I would prefer a more generic way where I can just extend a (abstract) base model class so I don't have to be careful not using ForeignKey instead of MyForeignKey.